# Scanning function HP Deskjet 1514

Tags: scanner

I am trying to get the Scanner function to work on my HP Deskjet 1514 all in one printer having installed new genuine ink cartridges. I can print the Alignment page for aligning the printers - but that is all! When I check to see the status of print jobs, I see a message saying 'printer paused' I have tried disconnecting the power & leaving it off for 5 minutes or so in the hope it might clear some sort of error? but that does nothing to resolve the printing problem! I therefore am guessing that I need to scan the alignment page? but that takes to my issue - how do I get the HP Deskjet 1514 scanner to work? My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Simple Scan` application which should be pre-installed.

If you can't find it, install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install simple-scan
```

See [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Simple_Scan/) for further information.

Comment: Many thanks xdevs23 for your answer & solution which has given me a novice Ubuntu user a working scanner / printer :-) I was not aware the function was already built in - The scanner icon is now locked onto the Toolbar.

Comment: No problem, I have locked it as well on mine.